# Failed to load IMA policy

Tags: linux, boot, suse

After updating Tumbleweed (SuSe rolling release distro) restarting freezes during boot emitting the message ***Failed to load IMA policy***.

Before that it sais: ***Starting Switch Root...***.

I tried to start in recovery mode and also with older kernels, but the results are always the same.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** does anyone have tumbleweed and a non empty file ***policy*** in a ***ima*** directory. If so, can you post it?

**UPDATE2** I have removed ***/etc/ima-policy*** file and now I can boot again. But I guess this file is important for security. So still need a better remedy.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could add "ima_appraise=fix" to the kernel boot parameters once
then read all files

```
time find / -fstype ext4 -type f -uid 0 -exec dd if='{}' of=/dev/null count=0 status=none \;
```

another possibility

```
zypper rm keylime-ima-policy dracut-ima
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).